# How do I compile QScintilla and Eric6 on Linux?

Tags: linux, compilation, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

First I install QScintilla by following steps:

1:

```
cd Qt4Qt5
qmake qscintilla.pro
sudo make
make install
```

2:

```
cd ../designer-Qt4Qt5
qmake designer.pro
sudo make
sudo make install
```

3:

```
cd ../Python
python3 configure.py --pyqt=PyQt5
sudo make
```

And here I met the problem :

```
QAbstractScrollArea: No such file or directory
```

and problem:

```
qprinter.h: No such file or directory
```

But I finally solved them by manually add required files.

Goes on:

```
sudo make install
```

4:

then I go to install eric6 by typing:

```
sudo python3 install.py
```

But I got:

> Checking dependencies
>
> Python Version: 3.4.0
>
> Found PyQt5
>
> Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
>   its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
>
> Error: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qsci.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QsciScintilla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are linking against Qt4 rather than Qt5. This is why the `QAbstractScrollArea` and `QPrinter` headers are reported as missing, and why you later get the `undefined symbol` error.

QScintilla uses a features file to control compile-time configuration, and its sources need to  be patched to get a good build for Qt5.

So first unpack a fresh set of sources, and then make these changes:

**designer-Qt4Qt5/designer.pro**:

```
TARGET = qscintillaplugin_qt5
```

**Qt4Qt5/features/qscintilla2.prf**:

```
        } else {
            LIBS += -lqscintilla2_qt5
        }
    }
} else {
    LIBS += -lqscintilla2_qt5
}
```

**Qt4Qt5/qscintilla.pro**:

```
TARGET = qscintilla2_qt5
...
features.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA]/mkspecs/features
```

This will ensure that you get independent qscintilla libs for Qt5.

With that done, take the following steps to build (as a normal user):

```bsh
cd 'path/to/src/Qt4Qt5'

# this is essential for correct linking
export QMAKEFEATURES="$PWD/features"

# make sure you use the right qmake!
qmake-qt5 'qscintilla.pro'
make

# plugin for Qt5 Designer
cd '../designer-Qt4Qt5'
qmake-qt5 'designer.pro' INCLUDEPATH+='../Qt4Qt5' QMAKE_LIBDIR+='../Qt4Qt5'
make

# Python bindings
cd '../Python'
python3 'configure.py' --pyqt='PyQt5' --qmake='/usr/bin/qmake-qt5' \
        --qsci-incdir='../Qt4Qt5' --qsci-libdir='../Qt4Qt5'
make
```

If successful, you can then install everything (as root):

```
cd 'path/to/src/Qt4Qt5'
make install

cd '../designer-Qt4Qt5'
make install

cd '../Python'
make install
```

Comment: Finally I solved the problem but more problems come after that. I install Qt5.4.1 under /opt, but from `from PyQt5 import QtCore;print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)` the version is 5.2.1, can you tell me how to make python use the version under /opt file?

Comment: @Zieng. See the comment in my answer: "make sure you use the right qmake!". You need to specify the full path of the qmake installed under `/opt` when compiling.

Comment: Now my problem is that I can't build the correct QtSql.so. I think this is nothing to do with QScintilla2 because while I install eric6 it said that "found QScintilla2", and it's nothing to do with qmake version because while I build PyQt5 or install Qt5 I didn't even use qmake. So ,what I am going to solve is find out how to build the correct QtSql.so.@ekhumoro

Comment: @ekhumoro.Finally I solved all problems by removing all the old version and re-install all the lattest version.Thank you Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

[ekhumoro's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739793/192127) did not quite work for me - let's just say maybe I missed something, or it's an environment-specific thing.

Anyway.... I did what ekhumoro advised ***except didn't edit these three files***:         (XXX)

```
- designer-Qt4Qt5/designer.pro
- Qt4Qt5/features/qscintilla2.prf
- Qt4Qt5/qscintilla.pro
```

the reason for editing them seems sound, but at the end of the day Eric install failed with:

```
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.
Error:     
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qsci.so, 2):
Library not loaded: libqscintilla2_qt5.12.dylib
                                  ^^^^
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qsci.so
Reason: image not found
```

note the _qt5 marked with ^^^^ - theoretically that should resolve, but for me it did not. I tried all kinds of things to no avail. May be my ignorance of some setting.

I expected ekhumoro's instructions to work, since the edits suggested for the 3 files - see (XXX) - configure Make to create libraries with _qt5.
I tried many things - symlinks, etcetc., but at the end of the day, leaving out (XXX) allowed everything to proceed properly.

So - in summary, ***if you don't need to have QScintilla work simultaneously with PyQt4 *and* PyQt5***, do ekhumoro's advice minus the stuff at (XXX) - that way, Eric should install without problems.

**Take care with the information above: it will probably clobber QScintilla libs for Qt4**

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most important is `--pyqt=PyQt5` which leads to using `sip/qscimod5.sip` instead of `sip/qscimod4.sip`. Difference is that it contains line `%Import QtWidgets/QtWidgetsmod.sip` which is essential for `QAbstractScrollArea`.